# The command with double quotes in the shell cannot be executed

Tags: shell

When I execute the following script, it will report an error, but if I manually execute the command of the echo, I will not report an error, they are clearly the same!

I tried to execute this script in Linux, Windows, they all report the same error. Although there is no command `MinGW Makefiles` on Linux, it will appreciate that even if there is, it will be reported. Because the error prompt is `Could not create named generator "MinGW` instead of `Could not create named generator "MinGW Makefiles"`

How can I fix this problem?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

compiler_options=(' -G "MinGW Makefiles"')

echo "cmake -S . -B build ${compiler_options}"
cmake -S . -B build ${compiler_options}
```

```sh
# run command
bash test.sh
```

```
# errorinfo
CMake Error: Could not create named generator "MinGW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using an array is to *avoid* cramming all the arguments into a single whitespace-delimited string.

```
#!/bin/bash

compiler_options=(-G "MinGW Makefiles")

echo "cmake -S . -B build ${compiler_options[*]}"
cmake -S . -B build "${compiler_options[@]}"
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the difference between `*` and `@` here, since it seems to be fashionable these days for people to not look up such things on their own.  That, or use `@` in both instances.

Comment: I'm torn. It's not critical to make the actual invocation of `cmake` work, so I'd rather not get into the technical details of why I used `*` for the log message, especially when people *can* look up such things on their own.